# can we login with keycloak using only username field

Tags: keycloak

I am running my web application using keycloak, so very first page display is Username and Password form. I want to create a flow i.e it should ask only for Username validation form and go next. How do I perform this task.

Comment: U dont want to ask password? Only through username you want to login into application?

Comment: Yes. I just want to ask username.

Comment: Do I need to do some extra settings on flow ?

Comment: But what about security of application ?

Comment: Better do the OpenId login in this case its better choice.

Comment: I want passwordless login and then i am going to ask secret question

Comment: this is all about security then only user get logged in to the system

Comment: Agree but first time in my IT career i am getting such requirement login without password as i know people implement OpenID implementation for that ,Even Stackoverflow done same .Another way to keycloak through access token but i think its NP for user to get accesstoken.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write custom authenticator which takes only username as input.
Then link the flow with security question flow when success.
[Link for custom authentication docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi)

Answer (score 0):

Newer Keycloak version (like 19) has `Username Form` authentication step.

When you remove default `Username Password Form` and add `Username Form` instead you should be able to login (**existing user**) just with this field.

[image]

[image]